# What's the origin of the phrase "God's clean earth", and how long has it been around?

Tags: phrases, expressions, history, errors

> "It isn't every day a man wakes up to discover he's a screaming bender with no more right to live on God's clean Earth than a weasel."
>
> - Dr. Leech, "Blackadder II"

What's the origin of that phrase, *God's clean earth*, and how long has it been in use? Google NGrams gives me nothing.

EDIT: Given it really does seem to come from this, I agree it's too localized and am chucking the final vote in to close it. Thanks again all!

Comment: Looks like the quote has been truncated. Perhaps it should be "...he's **on** a screaming bender..."? And, too, the syntax leaves much to be desired. When has a man had the right to live on a weasel?

Comment: @BillFranke, no: it's "he is a screaming bender". See [ODO *bender* sense 3](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bender)

Comment: @Andrew: I didn't know that "bender" means "male homosexual". Thank you for filling in my repertoire of unspeakable words. :-)

Comment: In that case, Brits must be rather bemused by the character of that name in Futurama.

Comment: @T.E.D. Fortunately, context is everything. When I first saw *Futurama*, Bender spent most of the episode bending things. In fact the other meaning never occurred to me. I'm not sure I shall be able to watch another episode in quite the same light again, though, now that you have mentioned it!

Comment: "God's clean earth" is not found by Ngrams, which presumably means it does not occur in any book.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Bender is also fond of a drink, see definition #2 in your link.

Comment: This question is Too Localised. As rajah9 points out, OP (or whoever he got this from) has simply misheard *"God's **green** Earth"*. Which is correctly rendered in [subtitle files](http://www.subtitleseeker.com/84988/The+Black+Adder/Tv-Subtitles/), and on [Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Blackadder)

Comment: @FumbleFingers the wikiquote page you link to has "clean", so do the subtitles on the DVD published by the BBC. And it sounds like "clean", or at a push, "geen", but definitely not "green". I suppose that makes it more localised though, since it's not an idiom, but solely from that script.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Weird. I forget now exactly what my Google search string was, but it definitely included ***green***, because that's what I was expecting and thus searching for. It might have been a deliberately larky Blackadder usage, but I'm not going to watch them all again to find it and check myself. I've got x.avi's of the entire Blackadder, so if you or someone else would like to post the episode (and time offset), I'd like to listen to *that* bit. But regardless of whether it's a mistranscription or a one-off "joke", it's still Too Localised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers someone put the audio at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EnddhETKc4#t=12m20s also, the BBC (the original broadcaster) DVD is quite clear in the subtitles.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry, that being Blackadder II, episode 1 ("Bells"), 12m20s in.

Comment: @Jon Hanna: Thanks. Yes, Dr. Leech definitely says ***clean*** there. But it's effectively a one-off (although I did find [half-a-dozen](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22god%27s+clean+earth%22&hl=en&biw=1149&bih=864&sa=X&ei=pbP2UPCrBdCR0QXm14DIDQ&ved=0CCYQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1900%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1984&tbm=bks) written instances from *before* that 1985 episode). Not that it's ever become established enough to be considered a "known phrase", and it surely wouldn't have been in the script at all if not for the "original".

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I Googled the phrase before posting here, I found a number of uses that suggests it's starting to become idiomatic. I've certainly heard my friends use it before. It's definitely "clean" not "green". I can believe that it originally came from Blackadder (surprises me, but I can believe it) so thanks to those who've helped establish this for me. (For the record, I'm a *she* not a *he* - possibly better to use *they* as a singular neutral pronoun?)

Comment: @Lunivore: Sorry about the gender bending! :) Well, Google Books has a [grand total of 19 instances](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22God's+clean+earth%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22God%27s+clean+earth%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=XWb3UMi_CJSq0AXKz4GACg&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.d2k&fp=9b5a984ea69791e9&biw=1149&bih=864) - of which a third predate Blackadder, as per previous comment. So it clearly *doesn't* "originate" there, even though I doubt Elton/Curtis had heard it before. Your friends are probably atypical if they say it repeatedly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers They're English; all of us are Blackadder fans. So, yes. :)

Comment: @Lunivore: I suppose the question is - do they say it knowing full well that it's a jokey Blackadder reference to the standard *God's green earth?* Which incidentally is [3-4 times more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=God%27s+green+earth&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=) in the US than in modern "secular" Britain. Anyway, that particular one hasn't quite achieved the popularity of Monty Python's [just one more wafer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXH_12QWWg8)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think they're the kind of people who'd refer to *God's green earth*; they may well have been referencing Blackadder without me realising though. As for Monty Python, I'd like to have an argument, please.

Comment: @Lunivore: If this question hadn't been closed (and thus unlikely to be read by so many people in future) we'd probably have the makings of a humdinger of an argument there. Any suggestion that only Brits still keep the memory of Monty Python alive would be torn into by Americans saying *"I was there at the [Hollywood Bowl](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lL9oA1LFoMw)"* (that's the exact sketch, which I hope you'll agree is a fitting response here! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is. Or should I say, It's...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin is that Ben Elton and Richard Curtis thought it up for that episode. You're allowed to be original.

The form "God's Earth" or "God's [adjective] Earth" (green, wide, and others) originates from the simple fact that the Christian god (normally referred to simply as "God") was creator of and authority over the earth:

> The earth is the LORD'S, and the fulness thereof; the world, and they that dwell therein. - Psalm 24:1

So, "God's anything earth" as a phrasing would come directly from this belief, which predates the English language.

Generally referencing something in terms of God or Christ when there is no real reason to do so, is a mild form of swearing that has been found in English since the Angles and Saxons were converted. (Ironically, since it's considered a sin to do so).

Elton & Curtis use *clean* to contrast against homophobic slurs which would would use metaphors of dirt and filth to insult gay people (the general statement is a homophobic insult).

Edit with hat-tip to rajah9:

And therefore we can be precise as to "how long has it been around", the episode first aired on the 9th of January, 1986 so it has been around twenty-seven years and one week. And since I remember it from that first airing, I now feel old.

Comment: What was the airing date of the episode? That would answer the part of the OP's question "How long has it been around?"

Comment: Good idea, @rajah9

Comment: Thank you. Given how many uses of it I found on the internet, I was curious (I just used it in an answer to someone on a forum, and found myself bemused).

Comment: Well, some people could well arrive at it independently, but I'd note also that google finds over 2million references for "I have a cunning plan".

Answer (score 4):

I have not watched this episode, but I suspect Dr. Leech said "God's green Earth," for which you will find considerably more hits.

Comment: There are [lots and lots](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="god's+clean+earth"+blackadder) of references to this being "God's clean earth".

Comment: @Andrew: But all those references come from _Black Adder II_. And all from the same speech, it seems. At least, that's what my browser presented me when I clicked on your link. Dr Leech must have lifted the phrase from Iran's current president: the earth in his country is apparently bereft of "screaming benders".

Comment: @BillFranke Exactly: in *Blackadder II* the speech is "God's clean earth". The question does not misquote Dr Leech, and this answer's stated suspicion is not well-founded.

Comment: When search on <<"God's clean earth" -blackadder>>, I get about seventy hits, several of which still reference weasels and benders. The earliest web reference was Jan 31, 2001. I'm sticking with my initial Mondegreen suspicion (http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mondegreen.html).

Comment: That proves nothing. Besides which, I *have* watched this episode, and he said "clean".

Comment: Just watched it again. Definitely "clean". Still a funny show, despite watching it so much I know every joke that's coming.

Comment: @JonHanna: I yield to the gentleman's parsing of the sentence.

Comment: I used the phrase in a forum, then wondered where on earth it came from, so I assume I must have heard it watching Blackadder itself.